# Synchronizing personal contacts in Outlook/WP6

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, windows-mobile, windows-phone, device-manager, activesync

I have a Windows Phone 6.5 device (HTC HD2) and I wanted to synchronize it with my PC's Outlook 2010 via WMDC.

The "problem" is that my Outlook, more than having a lcal list of personal contacts, stored on computer as usual, is connected to my work's Exchange server and has access to work's contact list.

I don't want to synchronize my phone with Exchange. I just want to get my personal contacts on it, full stop!!!

I found that WMDC shows me no option to select which contacts (local or Exchange) to synchronize with the phone.

How can I both access work mail/contacts from my Outlook **and** share at least my personal contacts with the phone?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way by myself.

It's very easy to fix, but hard to find out. I'm sharing the solution if the problem occurs to someone else.

Basically, Outlook stores personal local contacts in the "Local" data file (ie. Outlook.pst), but when I connected to Exchange *he* decided to use Exchange's local snapshot as **default** data file.

ActiveSync/WMDC looks for the default folder, so you have to restore it to local one.

Go to File\Account settings, data files, and choose the right .pst file as default file.

Then restart Outlook.

[image]